# Datepicker doesn't work after ajax reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with jquery Datapicker, i read here a lot of solution and test but anythings is work for me.
I explain my situation, i have a main page call index with this page a select a first container, in this container there are more element; When you select a item the index page call a another page for visualize the result in table form and you can select a filter for see only some data. I use datapicker for select the day.
When i select one item for the first time datapicker work but when i select another item datapicker stop working and trow this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'initialized' of undefined
    at HTMLDocument.eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.12.4.js:349), <anonymous>:20:21)
    at fire (jquery-1.12.4.js:3232)
    at Object.add [as done] (jquery-1.12.4.js:3291)
    at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.ready (jquery-1.12.4.js:3542)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.12.4.js:349), <anonymous>:14:14)
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at jquery-1.12.4.js:349
    at Function.globalEval (jquery-1.12.4.js:350)
    at domManip (jquery-1.12.4.js:6089)
    at jQuery.fn.init.append (jquery-1.12.4.js:6269)
```

This is how i call the datapicker:

```
$( ".datepickerINF" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
$( ".datepickerSUP" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });
```

I try to destroy this picker in the beginning then recreate them but doesn't work! 
Can someone help me? Thanks.
In the first image datapicker work then, when i select another item doesn't work anymore!
[image: Datapicker work here!]
[image: And here no more]

EDIT:
Here the code of the main page:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['choice'])){

        $bottone=$_POST['choice'];

        $query = mysql_query("SHOW TABLES;");    //This is the query for take the DB table
        if($query ==FALSE) {
            die();
        }
        if(mysql_num_rows($query)){

            $select= '<p class="selectTable">Select the Table<br/><select name="select" id="test" class="selectionTable">';  //Create the menu with the table of the DB.
            $select.= "<option>------</option>";
            while($rs=mysql_fetch_array($query)){
                $name=$rs[0];
                $nameTable="";
                $element=explode('_',$name);
                //echo $bottone;
                //print_r($element);
                if($element[0]==$bottone){
                        unset($element[0]);
                        $nameTable=$nameTable." ".$element[1];
                        $i=2;
                        while($i<=(count($element))){
                            $nameTable=$nameTable."_".$element[$i];
                            $i++;
                        }
                        $select.='<option value="'.$name.'">'.$nameTable.'</option>';
                        $nameTable="";
                }
              }
        }

    $select.='</select></p>';
    echo $select;
    }
    ?>
</div>
<br/><br/>
<div class="val" id="val" align="center"></div>
 <script>
  $(function() { /* Prepare the script */   

  $("#test").change(function(){ /* This event start when change the voice of the select */
    var tabella = $(this).val(); /* Take the string value from the table */
    if((tabella.localeCompare("------"))==0){
        alert("This is a default element, please select a table");
    }else{
        var dataString = "tabella="+tabella; /* save the result in a variable  */

        $.ajax({ /* Call ajax */
            type: "POST", /* How send the value */
            url: "value.php", /* This is the page where i send the value*/
            data: dataString, /* This is the value */
            success: function(result){ /* Take the data result */
                $("#val").html(result); /* Write the data in the div. */
                $("#val").show();
            }
            });
        }

    });
  });
</script>
```

and here the code of the other page (the datapicker part):

```
 <?php
    $filter="<div class='selector' id='selector'><p>Date: <input type='text' class='datepickerINF'>";
            //echo $filter;
            /*$filter= "<div class='selector' id='selector'>Filter start day: year <input id='dateYearStart' style='width:40px'/>";
            $filter.= " month (01-12) <input id='dateMonthStart' style='width:40px'/> day (01-31) <input id='dateDayStart' style='width:40px'/></br>";*/
            $filter.= "Time: <select id='hourLow'>";
            $filter.= "<option selected='selected'>------</option>";
            for($i=0;$i<24;$i++) {
                if($i<10) {$filter.= "<option value=0".$i.":00:00>"."0".$i.":00:00</option>";}
                else {$filter.= "<option value=".$i.":00:00>".$i.":00:00</option>";}
            }
            $filter.= "</select></p>";/*
            $filter.= "Filter End day: year <input id='dateYearEnd' style='width:40px'/>";
            $filter.= " month (01-12) <input id='dateMonthEnd' style='width:40px'/> day (01-31) <input id='dateDayEnd' style='width:40px'/></br>";*/
            $filter.="<p>Date: <input type='text' class='datepickerSUP'>";
            $filter.= "Time: <select id='hourHight'>";
            $filter.= "<option selected='selected'>------</option>";
            for($i=0;$i<24;$i++) {
                if($i<10) {$filter.= "<option value=0".$i.":00:00>"."0".$i.":00:00</option>";}
                else {$filter.= "<option value=".$i.":00:00>".$i.":00:00</option>";}
            }
            $filter.= "</select><br/></p>
                If you leave the default value for the hour (default: '------')<br/> you will take all the day (from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59).
                </br>";

            $filter.="<button id='filterSend'>Filter Results</button></div>";

            echo $filter;
            $exCSV="<div id='ex' class='ex'><button id='exportCSV' >Export CSV</button><br/></div>";
            echo $exCSV;
        }

    ?>
 $(document).ready(function() {




    /* Initialise the date picker. */
    applyDatepicker(".datepickerINF");
    applyDatepicker(".datepickerSUP");
    ...


    function applyDatepicker(elem) {
        $( elem ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' });

    }   
</script>
```

When the main page load the second of course datepicker work but when i change table and reload the page it compare the error.

Comment: the error in your screenshot isn't the same as the error you've shown in the text?? The error in the screenshot is simply because you haven't included the jQuery datepicker JS file in your page.

Comment: I have insert in all file this:
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: ok well either those references are getting removed somehow, or they're not loading properly or something. Without seeing the rest of your code and how you're using this it's pretty hard to say anything. A screenshot and an error message are useful but the code is the most important thing.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you need to understand that ajax does not reload a page. Ajax just do the work and return to the same page.
As you didnt put the code of ajax calling, the problem is not clear.
One thing to try is call datepicker again after ajax call. But that is a bad solution.